# Water well electric source

Tags: water, well

The electric source of my water well is a circuit box on a house that is to be demolished.  I want to keep the electricity to the water well.  What are my options?

Comment: Are you in the US or somewhere else?

Comment: How far away from your house is the water well?

Comment: Also, can you get us the nameplate data on the well pump?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're in the US, what you'll need to do is the following (an electrician might be a good idea for some of this)

1. Mount a pole near to where the pump is. A pressure treated 4x4 would work for this
2. Mount a meter box. If you're doing this yourself, you can sometimes find these with the mast pre-attached and utility ready
3. Attach a breaker box to the meter. There's a lot of these with only a few breaker slots (think a 100 amp panel)
4. A GFCI breaker for however many amps the pump draws. My bet is a 20 amp would do
5. Thick enough UF wire and conduit to reach to the pump. 12-2 would be sufficient if 20 amps was for the previous step

Once this is all set, have the utility come out and connect to the box and install a meter. And that's it.